# Regular expressions in sed

Tags: regex, sed

I have a stream that looks like this (except with more stuff):

```
<ret:EditUse>Broadcast</ret:EditUse>
<EditUse>Movie</EditUse>
```

and I'm trying to clean the XML from it using sed:

```
sed "s_</?(ret:)?EditUse>__"
```

I've tested the regular expression using RegexPal but it doesn't seem to work in sed. Any ideas as to what's wrong?

Comment: [The pony he comes...](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/554546)

Comment: I'm not trying to parse xml, I'm trying to strip it. I believe regex is perfectly suitable for this specific task, especially because EditUse is the only tag that shows up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the regex that works with `sed`:

```
sed "s_</\?\(ret:\)\?EditUse>__g"
```

1. Escape with backslash characters `?`, `(` and `)`
2. Use `g` switch to apply the regex many times in each line.

Result:

```
Broadcast
Movie
```

Comment: It works without escaping if you use `-r` option (it enables extended regular expressions).

Comment: @KL-7: Yes. You are right. It's good to know that command-line option but also that it is a GNU extension and less portable.